# Why cannot we use ruleset within the same ruleset?

Tags: less, less-mixins

I am trying to use the same `.formater()` ruleset within itself.
I am getting syntax error.

Why cannot we use a ruleset within itself?

```
.formater(@className;@rules){
    .@{className}{
        @rules();
    }
}

.formater(mainContainer;{
    display:block;
    line-height:2em;
    & a{
       colour: blue;
       &.formater(link;{
         colour:red;
       });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `&` before `.formater` inside the ruleset. Remove it and the code should compile fine. If you want the output to be like `.mainContainer a.link` then it'd be better to add the `&` to the `.formater()` mixin itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the syntax error is because you are appending `&` to a mixin call which is not allowed. `&` can be attached only to selectors. If you remove the `&` from before the mixin call then your code would compile fine.

```css
.formater(@className; @rules){
  .@{className}{
    @rules();
  }
}

.formater(mainContainer; {
  display:block;
  line-height:2em;
  & a{
    colour: blue;
    .formater(link; {
      colour:red;
    });
  }
});
```

The above Less code when compiled would produce the following CSS:

```css
.mainContainer {
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.mainContainer a {
  colour: blue;
}
.mainContainer a .link {
  colour: red;
}
```

---

As you would have noticed, the final selector that is output above is `.mainContainer a .link` and not `.mainContainer a.link`. If you are trying to achieve the latter then one option would be for you to add the `&` within the `.formater` mixin's code itself.

```css
.formater(@className; @rules) {
  &.@{className} {
    @rules();
  }
}
```

---

I wouldn't really recommend using the below option but if you need the `.formater()` mixin to support both variations then you could use a variable along with guard conditions and use as appropriate.

```css
.formater(@className; @rules; @parent-append: false) {
  & when not (@parent-append = false) {
    &.@{className} {
      @rules();
    }
  }
  & when (@parent-append = false) {
    .@{className} {
      @rules();
    }
  }  
}
```

You can then call the mixin as

```css
.formater(link; {colour:red;}; true); /* if & should be appended */
```

or

```css
.formater(link; {colour:red;};); /* if & need not be appended */
```

Comment: How do you have solutions for all of my problems :). Yes it is true that I am still learning lesscss and this is the best way possible. Thank you Harry and Stackoverflow :)